# Get center coords after drag & pan finished

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I would like to keep track of the coordinates of the center of my map. So far I've been using this:

```
// On Drag End
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'dragend', function() { 
    $('.map_center_coords .latitude').html( map.getCenter().lat() );
    $('.map_center_coords .longitude').html( map.getCenter().lng() );
});
```

which works by getting the coords at the end of the drag event.

The problem is I'm now using `map.panTo` to move to a certain location.

Is there an event for basically `"whenever the center has *finished* moving in any way"`?

As mentioned by geocodezip, I forgot about the `center_changed` event. But that event is continuously fired while the map is being dragged/panned.

Ideally I'm looking for an event that is only fired once, after any dragging/panning is done.

Comment: You will need to define what you mean by "finished". There is no such general event, you will need to implement it yourself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Observe the idle-event instead(*This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or zooming*):

```
    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'idle',function(){
      if(!this.get('dragging') && this.get('oldCenter') && this.get('oldCenter')!==this.getCenter()) {
        //do what you want to
      }
      if(!this.get('dragging')){
       this.set('oldCenter',this.getCenter())
      }

    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragstart',function(){
      this.set('dragging',true);          
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(map,'dragend',function(){
      this.set('dragging',false);
      google.maps.event.trigger(this,'idle',{});
    });
```

Answer (score 5):

The [google.maps.Map](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map) center_changed event.

```
center_changed | None | This event is fired when the map center property changes.
```

```
// On center changed
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'center_changed', function() { 
  $('.map_center_coords .latitude').html( map.getCenter().lat() );
  $('.map_center_coords .longitude').html( map.getCenter().lng() );
});
```

Comment: Thanks I forgot about this one but actually it's not exactly what I'm looking for. This one continuously fires while you're dragging and while you're panning. Ideally I would like something that fires only after drag/pan are finished. (Updating question)

Answer (score 3):

Try using `idle` event. Link to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map).

> This event is fired when the map becomes idle after panning or
>   zooming.

If you want **idle event to fire only after dragend** then try the snippet below.

This code prints coordinates to console after both `dragend` and `idle` events fire.

```
mapObj.addListener('dragend', function () {
    var idleListener = mapObj.addListener('idle', function () {
        google.maps.event.removeListener(idleListener);
        console.log(mapObj.getCenter().lat()); 
        console.log(mapObj.getCenter().lng());
    });
});
```